# What law that took effect in roughly the last year changed nutritional information requirements for restaurants and cafes?

Tags: england-and-wales, food, food-processing, labelling

Apparently some new law requires more detailed calorific information for prepared food items.

Is the same law also responsible for introducing further protections from contamination of allergens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The piece of legislation is the [Calorie Labelling (Out of Home Sector) (England) Regulations 2021](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2021/909/contents/made). It came into force on 6 April 2022.

There is no mention in it of contamination due to allergens.

Comment: There are many [exemptions](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2021/909/regulation/4/made) to the requirement.

Comment: About exemption "(b) food which is included on a menu for less than 30 consecutive days, and less than a total of 30 days in any calendar year." Does this mean they can serve up any advert-enhanced crap, and periodically rename it as a supposedly different dish (perhaps with a minor change to its ingredients), without stating its calorie content?

Comment: @WeatherVane sounds like something that will need to be tested in the courts.